# 1989 suzuki gsxr750 slingshot k

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, suzuki, ignition-coil

Had bike tuned up new plugs carb tuned new gas bike starts cold runs great when bike is hot will start but only idle won't rev over 1000rpm can't drive let cool down runs drives great

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did it run okay going into the shop and you were just looking to do routine maintenance? How long after cold startup will it run okay?

Comment: Get the coils checked, they could be starting to fail when warm.  Are they individual stick coils on GSXRs?  If so there might have been damage while they were being removed/replaced for plug replacement.  Also have you ruled out a fuelling issue?  A blocked tank breather would allow the bike to run for a while and then start struggling.